Debug: Error running 'bot' Argument for @NotNull parameter 'module' of com/intellij/openapi/roots/ModuleRootManager.getInstance must not be null
I clonned a repository from GitLab, when I first tried to debug the script in Pycharm, this error message was being thrown: "Error running 'bot' Argument for @NotNull parameter 'module' of com/intellij/openapi/roots/ModuleRootManager.getInstance must not be null"
I've tried some few tips that I found, on "Edit Configurations' such as: select 'Emulate in output console' or 'Run with Python console' and set '$FileDir$' parameters, any of it worked at first, I was conserned to try some others.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There wasn't a code, was just like a popup message in the IDE pointing to debug icon. I didn't take a print of it, and after I could solve it didn't happend again.

Among some the tips that I came across I had a clue, then I did something that worked for me 100%.
In your '.idea' folder inside your project folder check specifically the name of the file with extension '.iml'
After this, open the file 'workspace.xml' check for the tag named 'module' (< module name="name"/ >) compare if the name there is the same as the file '.iml'
Look through all of the 'module' tags and if the name is differente of the name of the '.iml' file change it for the actual "project name" which is that of the '.iml' file.

Thanks, you gave me a direction.
I closed IDE, renamed .idea to .idea_old, restarted IDE and reconfigured,  now is working properly.
